# Getting percentages calculation of items in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have items in a table, Task and Status

```
**TASK**  **STATUS**
task1     N/A 
task1     N/A
task1     Yes
task1     Yes
task1     No
task2     No
task2     Yes
```

I am attempting to get the percentage of each task that complete is set to yes and not N/A.

In order to get the total value of tasks I use this sql

```
select tasks, count(*) as count from mytable where status <> 'NA' group by tasks
```

Is there a way in a single sql to get a percentage value of unique tasks where Status = Yes and not equal to N/A ?

Comment: update your question and show the expected  result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select tasks, count(*) as count
       , count(*) * 100 / (select count(*)
                           from mytable
                           where status <> 'NA' and status = 'yes') as percent                
from mytable 
where status <> 'NA' and status = 'yes' 
group by tasks
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like this method:

```
select tasks,
       avg(status <> 'NA')
from mytable
group by tasks;
```

MySQL treats a boolean value as an integer when a number is expected, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  So, the average of the value gives the proportion.  You can multiply by 100 if you want a "percentage".